# A Gaussian scale mixture representation of the logistic distribution

Tags: probability, mixture-distribution, logistic-distribution

Can the logistic distribution with density function
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1 + e^{-x}\right)^2}$$
be represented as a Gaussian scale mixture? In other words, if
\begin{align*}
X|V &\sim N(0, V) \\
V &\sim g,
\end{align*}
is there a choice for $V$ which leads to $X$ having a marginal logistic distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This paper](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.4/8438/ISMS__1070R.pdf?sequence=1) by Leonard A. Stefanski (1991) illustrates that the answer to this question is yes, although the mixing density $g$ is difficult to work with in practice. Mixing over a Gamma density with a particular choice of parameters can also be shown to provide an extremely good approximation to the logistic distribution.

### Exact Result

Stefanski (1991) demonstrates that the logistic distribution can be represented as a Gaussian scale mixture by setting $\sqrt V \sim q$, where $q(x) = \frac{d}{dx}L(x/2)$ and $L$ is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution) cumulative distribution function. In the present notation, the density corresponding to $g$ becomes
$$g(v) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^2\exp\left(-\frac{n^2v}{2}\right)$$

This distribution can be difficult to work with in practice. This infinite series must be truncated after a finite number terms, and may be expensive to compute when $v$ is small (in fact, $g(v)$ will be negative for small $v$, unless you remember to choose an odd number for the truncation parameter). Working with $\log g(v)$ offers no improvement. Moreover, it is not easy to generate random variates from $g(v)$ and full conditionals will be intractable when using Gibbs sampling.

### Approximation via Gamma

For the reasons described in the previous paragraph, it would be convenient to have an alternative choice for $g$ which leads to a marginal logistic distribution for $X$. The gamma distribution is easy to compute, easy to simulate from and often leads to tractable distributions during Gibbs sampling. Thus we consider the scale mixture representation.
\begin{align*}
X|V &\sim N(0, V) \\
V &\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta),
\end{align*}
Note the following.
\begin{align*}
\mu = E(X) &= 0 \\[1.5ex]
\sigma^2 = Var(X) = E(Var(X|V)) + Var(E(X|V)) = E(V) &= \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \\[1.5ex]
\kappa = E\left[\left(\frac{X-0}{\sqrt{\alpha/\beta}}\right)^4\right] = \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} E\left[V^2\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt V}\right)^4\right] = \frac{3\beta^2}{\alpha^2}E(V^2) &= 3\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1\right)
\end{align*}
Using a simple moment-matching approach, we set
$$3\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+1\right) = \frac{21}{6} \quad\quad\quad \frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{\pi^2}{3},$$
where $21/6$ and $\pi^2/3$ are the kurtosis and variance, respectively, of the logistic distribution. Solving for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ gives
$$\alpha = 2.5 \quad\quad \beta = \frac{7.5}{\pi^2} = 0.75991\ldots.$$

### Marginal Distribution of $X$

The joint distribution of $X$ and $V$ can be written as
$$f(x, v) = cv^{\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(2\beta v + x^2\frac{1}{v}\right)\right), v > 0, x \in \mathbb R.$$
By noticing that this function is proportional (in $v$) to a [generalized inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution, we can derive the marginal distribution of $X$ as having density
$$f(x) = \frac{\beta^{\frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{4}}}{2^{\frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{3}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\alpha)}|x|^{\alpha-1/2}K_{\alpha-1/2}\left(\sqrt{2\beta}|x|\right),$$
where $K_p(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. In the special case where $\alpha=2.5$ and $\beta = 7.5/\pi^2$, this density reduces to

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3375}}{3\pi^4}x^2K_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{\pi}|x|\right)$$

Note that this is a special case of the [Bessel function distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution).

### Numerical Simulations

```
#Simulate data
set.seed(1234)
N <- 1e5
V <- rgamma(N, 2.5, 7.5/pi^2)
X <- rnorm(N, 0, sqrt(V))

#Plot samples
hist(X, freq=F, breaks=100, xlim=c(-8, 10), main="")

# Plot logistic density
curve(dlogis(x), add=T, lwd=3, col='red', lty=2)

# Plot derived density
curve(sqrt(3375)/(3*pi^4)*x^2*besselK(sqrt(15)/pi*abs(x), 2), add=T, col='blue', lwd=3, lty=3)
legend('topright', c("Logistic", "Gamma-Mixture"), lwd=3, lty=c(2,3), col=c('red', 'blue'), bty='n', cex=1.2)

#Make QQ Plot
q_logis <- qlogis(seq(0, 1, length.out=N+2)[-c(1,N+2)])
qqplot(X, q_logis,
   xlab="Sample Quantiles", ylab="Theoretical Quantiles")
abline(0, 1, lwd=2, col='red', lty=3)
```

[image: histogram and density curves]

[image: qqplot of samples vs logistic]